# Can't properly modify dictionary in Python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary

I've incurred in a strange problem while I was trying to modify a list of dictionaries in a class. This is the smallest reproducible code that shows the behaviour :

```
from itertools import product

class Test():
    def __init__(self, grid):
        self.grid = grid
        self.pc =  [dict(zip(self.grid, v)) for v in product(*self.grid.values())]
        for i in range(0, len(self.pc)):
            self.pc[i]['sim_options']['id'] = i

grid = {
    'k': [5, 10, 15, 20],
    'sim_options': [
        {'name': 'cosine', 'batched': True},
        {'name': 'pearson', 'batched': True}
    ]
}
t = Test(grid)
```

What I'd expect as output is the following :

```
[{'k': 5, 'sim_options': {'name': 'cosine', 'batched': True, 'id': 0}},
 {'k': 5, 'sim_options': {'name': 'pearson', 'batched': True, 'id': 1}},
 {'k': 10, 'sim_options': {'name': 'cosine', 'batched': True, 'id': 2}},
 {'k': 10, 'sim_options': {'name': 'pearson', 'batched': True, 'id': 3}},
 {'k': 15, 'sim_options': {'name': 'cosine', 'batched': True, 'id': 4}},
 {'k': 15, 'sim_options': {'name': 'pearson', 'batched': True, 'id': 5}},
 {'k': 20, 'sim_options': {'name': 'cosine', 'batched': True, 'id': 6}},
 {'k': 20, 'sim_options': {'name': 'pearson', 'batched': True, 'id': 7}}]
```

and yet I get :

```
[{'k': 5, 'sim_options': {'name': 'cosine', 'batched': True, 'id': 6}},
 {'k': 5, 'sim_options': {'name': 'pearson', 'batched': True, 'id': 7}},
 {'k': 10, 'sim_options': {'name': 'cosine', 'batched': True, 'id': 6}},
 {'k': 10, 'sim_options': {'name': 'pearson', 'batched': True, 'id': 7}},
 {'k': 15, 'sim_options': {'name': 'cosine', 'batched': True, 'id': 6}},
 {'k': 15, 'sim_options': {'name': 'pearson', 'batched': True, 'id': 7}},
 {'k': 20, 'sim_options': {'name': 'cosine', 'batched': True, 'id': 6}},
 {'k': 20, 'sim_options': {'name': 'pearson', 'batched': True, 'id': 7}}]
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong, am I not iterating over a list, accessing the `'sim_options'` field of the i-th list and creating a new key-value pair ('id':i) in that dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the dictionaries are getting updated by reference, so whatever you do to one, happens to the other.

You can check this with the [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function:

```
for i in range(0, len(self.pc)):
    print(id(self.pc[i]['sim_options']))
    self.pc[i]['sim_options']['id'] = i
```

Which gives me the same repeating reference identities(`2078935351104` and `2078964975104`) for both dictiionaries in `'sim_options'`:

```
2078935351104
2078964975104
2078935351104
2078964975104
2078935351104
2078964975104
2078935351104
2078964975104
```

One way to get around this is to copy options, which will give you a different reference identity. I've modified your code slightly to make this possible using `copy()`. It also uses [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to loop over the indices and items, which is much nicer to use than `range(len(...))` when you need both.

```
from itertools import product
from pprint import pprint

class Test:
    def __init__(self, grid):
        self.grid = grid

        self.pc = []
        for i, (k, options) in enumerate(product(self.grid["k"], self.grid["sim_options"])):
            temp = {"k": k, "sim_options": options.copy()}
            temp["sim_options"]["id"] = i
            self.pc.append(temp)

    def get(self):
        return self.pc

grid = {
    "k": [5, 10, 15, 20],
    "sim_options": [
        {"name": "cosine", "batched": True},
        {"name": "pearson", "batched": True},
    ],
}

t = Test(grid)

pprint(t.get())
```

Or just build a new list of dictionaries with a list comprehension. I usually find this way much more preferable.

```
self.pc = [
    {"k": k, "sim_options": {**option, "id": idx}}
    for idx, (k, option) in enumerate(
        product(self.grid["k"], self.grid["sim_options"])
    )
]
```

Output:

```
[{'k': 5, 'sim_options': {'batched': True, 'id': 0, 'name': 'cosine'}},
 {'k': 5, 'sim_options': {'batched': True, 'id': 1, 'name': 'pearson'}},
 {'k': 10, 'sim_options': {'batched': True, 'id': 2, 'name': 'cosine'}},
 {'k': 10, 'sim_options': {'batched': True, 'id': 3, 'name': 'pearson'}},
 {'k': 15, 'sim_options': {'batched': True, 'id': 4, 'name': 'cosine'}},
 {'k': 15, 'sim_options': {'batched': True, 'id': 5, 'name': 'pearson'}},
 {'k': 20, 'sim_options': {'batched': True, 'id': 6, 'name': 'cosine'}},
 {'k': 20, 'sim_options': {'batched': True, 'id': 7, 'name': 'pearson'}}]
```